# Reference to Translator in Symfony2 event

Tags: symfony

I know I can use this in a controller:

```
$this->get('translator')->trans('key_name')
```

...but how do I get reference to the translator in a Symfony2 GetResponseEvent or FilterResponseEvent event?

I know I can use ->getRequest() but I don't see how I can get it from the Request object either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `services.yml` you just need to add `@translator` service reference

<kbd>**services.yml**</kbd>

```
services:
    mylistener:
        class: Your\Bundle\Listener\RequestListener
        arguments: [ @translator ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

<kbd>**Your/Bundle/Listener/RequestListener.php**</kbd>

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Listener;

use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class RequestListener
{
    protected $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $this->translator->trans('key_name');
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in Symfony 3. The argument [ @translator ] is invalid YAML. [ '@translator'] passes the YAML test but isn't passed into the constructor as a valid TranslatorInterface type